# CR Rejection / Approval based on the Technical Feasibility

Tags: software-development, requirements, change-management

I have a concern with regards to CR rejection / approval process.

A client presents his / her requirement to the PM and PM asks them to raise a change request, but once the requirement is analyzed, it reveals out that it is not technically feasible to develop.

My question is, can an already raised CR be rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's the idea of a CR.  It can be accepted, rejected, deferred, delayed, etc. In fact, a change denial before it begins the process is damaging to the overall project, though it likely happens a lot on many projects and maybe even more so in certain industries.  Similarly, a change accepted before it starts the process is scope creep by definition.

It's interesting that you called this a CR *rejection/*approval process and then asked if it was appropriate for it to be rejected, which is part of the process's name.  So I sense there is another, more accurate question to your concern.  I am wondering if it has to do with the costs incurred during the technical feasibility analysis, i.e., if rejected so too are all costs associated with it.

Comment: What I wanted to know was that once the PM raises the CR and then the technical feasibility is carried out which results in a negative outcome to reject the CR, can a response be sent to the client stating that the requested CR is not technically feasible, hence it has to be rejected. What I thought was documenting the CR kind of reflects to the customer that the CR has been officially accepted. Anyway, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: If the customer is unaware of how a normal CR process works, then that might be true.  However, the customer should be on the change board and, in reality, is the one making the decision for a go or no go decision.